# Are Custom Metadata Types considered External Data Sources?

Tags: custom-metadata, externalobjects, winter19

Back in 2016 we created a Custom Metadata Type with about 3000 rows. There is a trigger that reads all 3000 rows (via SOQL) and creates a map. This has been working for years, until Winter '19.

Now, when we run the test Class for our trigger (in winter '19), we get this error message:

> System.QueryException: myCustom__mdt received too many records from the external data source

Summer '18 Orgs work just fine like they always have.

SO! When I try to debug that error message, I find this knowledge article.
[Too many records received from external data source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268360&language=en_US&type=1/%22Too%20many%20records%20received%20from%20external%20data%20source%22)

This basically says:

> When using an External data source configured to use Server Driven Pagination and for a query on an external object from this external source results in server responding with a result page size greater than 2000 records results in the below error - ...

SO! Are Custom Metadata Types treated like external data sources and the limit is only now being enforced in Winter '19? Is there a limit on CMTs that I am violating and can't find a reference to?

Comment: Whoa. That's crazy.

Comment: I opened a Case with SF Support... it's been escalated to the point where R&D is looking into it. I *think* it's a winter '19 bug. I *hope* it gets cleared up before release. I've been the little voice behind a known issue before, but never something like this!

Comment: Does it work if you query once with LIMIT 1500 and then another with OFFSET 1500 and merge them? Slapdash non-scalable solution but at least it gets you through the storm.

Comment: @CharlesT I haven't tried it. A member of our Dev team was heading down that path while we awaited and answer from support. I might get some feedback on this tommorow. "Slapdash", I like that! I'm going to start using that term I learned from Charles T.

Comment: Has anyone escalated this to the Partner Community?

Comment: @AdrianLarson can we add a new "Winter19" tag. I'd like to add that to the question, but there isn't such a tag.

Comment: You can always add a new tag to a post, as long as you have 300+ reputation.

Comment: This should be resolved in production now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Winter '19 bug. I've heard several other folks have the same issue and they put in tickets.

[Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HlNRQA0&title=error-type-name-__mdt-received-too-many-records-from-the-external-data-source-when-querying-2000-custom-metadata-type-records)

Comment: Confirmed by SFDC... "As informed, this is confirmed as a known issue in Salesforce. This is likely to be fixed by 1st week of October(safe harbour). Until then as a workaround you can try to modify the query to retrieve 2000 records."

Comment: In case anyone is following.. this appears to be fixed in Winter '19